# AT Modem picks up, occasionally phone keeps ringing, "DIGITAL LINE DETECTED"

Tags: java, serial-port, at-command, modem

I have an at-modem connected to my raspberry pi and an application communicating with the modem acting as a call-manager. My application has two main functions:

- Block calls based on callerid info
- Pickup calls with suppressed number, play an audio file, then record message.

Most of the time it works absolutely fine. However I have multiple issues:

- With ATE1 (command repetition enabled), it sometimes happens that the first character will get lost ("AT+VCID=1" becomes "T+VCID=1"). On rare occasions the first character will be duplicated ("AT+VCID=1" becomes "AAT+VCID=1"). So far these commands execute fine, my application currently has to stupidly account for these missing characters and duplications.
- **My main issue: About 1 in 10 calls I accept, the modem replies with CONNECT and sends and receives data (as it should), however the phone still rings (the phone I have on the landline rings, as well as the mobile phone I am using to call my landline). What will happen then as the modem sends and receives audio data, the modem will send the DLE commands 20 (DC4) and 23 (ETB) to my application. The manual (link below) does not say anything about those codes when specifying the commands send to and received from the modem during voice mode. See manual page 194 / 6.1.1**
- During dirty resets (I kill the app or reboot the pi), the first call I make will not have any callerid info with it. The calls after work absolutely fine. I seem to be able to circumvent this by powering off the modem completely (as rebooting the pi does not do this), or closing the port gracefully.

Issues 1 and 3 are not a problem for me, however I am listing these as well because I do not know if they are related to my main issue or not.

My application is written in Java and uses jSerialComm for communication. I have however used rxtx first which did not make a different in regards to the above mentioned issues. The only thing I noticed was a 10% cpu load using rxtx even when the application did nothing on my part, with jSerialComm that is done.

I use the same serialport-parameters that minicom uses when I connect to the modem with it. Code below.

```
this.port = SerialPort.getCommPort("/dev/ttyACM0");
this.port.openPort();
this.port.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING | SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0, 0);
this.port.setComPortParameters(115200, 8, SerialPort.ONE_STOP_BIT, SerialPort.NO_PARITY);
this.port.setFlowControl(SerialPort.FLOW_CONTROL_RTS_ENABLED | SerialPort.FLOW_CONTROL_CTS_ENABLED);

this.in = port.getInputStream();
this.out = port.getOutputStream();
```

Commands I use to initialize the modem:

```
ATE1
AT+GCI=42
AT+FCLASS=8
AT+VCID=1
```

And to accept the voice call and get into receive and transmit mode:

```
AT+VSM=1
AT+VLS=1
AT+VTR
```

Commands I convert to ISO-8859-1 and append \r\n before sending them. I also follow the manuals advice and have more than 100ms wait time in between the modem sending a reply message and the next command.

**EDIT: I analyzed the raw dump of the output data I get from the modem, and after a short period of silence (1-2 seconds) the data output contains:
"DIGITAL LINE DETECTED". Again, the manual lists this as a possible response code (in general, not specific to anything) without explanation.**

Manual:
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1140976/Conexant-Cx93010.html

Amazon link to the modem I purchased:
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B016MXLCEQ/

Comment: I could manage to fix the flow control issue. The trick is to flush the buffer after each and every single byte you send, and not on a per-command basis.

Comment: so what was causing DIGITAL LINE DETECTED to be returned? I have same problem

Comment: @jeppla I had to give up and return the device. I have gotten a USRobotics one instead, which is only half-duplex, but even then unusable as an answering device because switching duplex directions takes the modem 10(!) seconds. Support just decided to ignore me. Anyway, it depends on what device you are using. Are you using the exact same device (same amazon link, not the same picture)? The modem I used had a threshold command for the overcurrent protection that was supposedly being triggered which didn't help and when purposefully setting that setting low the behavior was slightly different.

Comment: I gave up using modems for the implementation trying to use raspbx instead. I used this one https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00XW5QYWS